# Authentication using ADFS 2.0 is not woking

Tags: windows-server-2008, authentication, adfs

I'm trying to configure ADFS 2.0 with thinktecute STS as an SP. The relying party has been configured successfully using the RP metadata. But when an authentication request is being sent to the ADFS 2.0 STS, it is trying to authenticate and it is failing although the user is a valid user in the server. It is just re-showing the authentication prompt in the browser again and again.

I can find in the Event viewer of the windows server the following logs in the security log:

> An account was successfully logged on.

Then

> An account was logged off.

Immediately.

Any clue why this is happening? Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

There could be a missing attribute for that user. How do you do the transformation? Do you also take into consideration some group membership? Another think that it might help you is trying to get something to see the responses when the user tries to access it and looking on the ADFS server for the event where the user accesses it(like fiddler or IE developer mode). This can be also related to browser versions(had some issues with CRM and certain IE versions).